# Make the list drop down using VBA (data validation)

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I want a cell to **drop down** its data validation list. I do NOT want to "create a drop-down data validation list". I already have the list, I simply want it to drop down using VBA.

Is there any way to do this?

Example:
If I put data in cell A1, I want cell B1 to be selected and its data validation list should drop down. I already have the code for selecting cell B1 if cell A1 has any values, but I haven't figured out how to make the cell's list drop down.

Example code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Sh1
        ' If row 1 in active column has a "1" in it, 
        ' we want to select the column to the right and drop down its list
        If .Cells(1, Target.Column).Value = 1 And Target.Value <> "" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Select
            ' Code for dropping down the cell's list
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "drop down its data validation list"??? Please explain with example and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the cell and use:

```
Application.SendKeys ("%{UP}")
```

Not at my computer so I can't verify, but if you need more help look here:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/789601-excel-2010-visual-basic-applications-code-open-drop-down-list.html

Answer (score 0):

If your `NumLock` button is being turned off, use the `SendKeys` twice with `DoEvents`.

```
    Application.SendKeys ("%{UP}")
    DoEvents
    Application.SendKeys ("%{UP}")
```

Worked with me. :)